# How Facebook/Gmail's 'logout from other devices' works?

Tags: php, session, browser, authentication, device

Anyone can please tell me how Facebook/Gmail's 'logout from other devices' works?I'm developing a website with a login system and I want user will be able to login from multiple devices and remotely log out from other devices.

In the login system I've developed a cookie will be created when a user logs in with the 'remember me' option checked and a key will be stored in the database.It is possible to log out user from a browser by deleting those keys for respective browser/ip.
But what if user doesn't checks the 'remember me' option?I'm stuck here..

Comment: U need to store a hash per browser+ip+user in the database and if someone tries to log in with a cookie validate against this hash. So if you "logout" on other devices  you clear the appropiate hashes so the cookies don't validate anymore.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should go with oAuth to provide secure delegated access to your website resources. Generate authentication token to log into the website from different devices. If the user selects remember me option, encrypt and store the user credentials (including oAuth token) in local machine. Nullify these credentials if user logs out.

Comment: Thanks for your answer..But still I want to know how remote logout system works.